# ReactJS: Triggering event onBlur

Tags: reactjs

I am having child component for input fields which is checking its validation `onBlur` event.

Child component usage:

```
<TextInput
    id={'lastName'}
    label={'Last name'}
    required={true}
    minChars={3}
    maxChars={25}
/>
```

Child component code:

```
onBlur(event) {
    // logic here
}

render() {
    let props = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor={props.id}>{props.label}</label>
                <input
                    id={props.id}
                    type={props.type}
                    className="form-control"
                    onBlur={this.onBlur.bind(this)}
                />
                <p className="text-danger">{this.error}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This works just fine.

When user submits form from parent component, I would like onBlur to be triggered across all inputs. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

In the parent component:

```
_handleBlur (eventData) {}

render () {
    const handleBlur = this._handleBlur.bind(this);

    return (
        <form>
            <ChildComponent onBlur={handleBlur} {...moreProps} />
            <ChildComponent onBlur={handleBlur} {...moreProps} />
            <ChildComponent onBlur={handleBlur} {...moreProps} />
            <button type="submit" onClick={handleBlur}>Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

In the child component:

```
render () {
    const props = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor={props.id}>{props.label}</label>
                <input
                    id={props.id}
                    type={props.type}
                    className="form-control"
                    onBlur={props.onBlur}
                />
                <p className="text-danger">{this.error}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Based on eventData or other params, you can define which field needs to be blurred. I don't know what exactly needs to happen on blur. In some cases it might be better to split it into a handleBlur and handleBlurAll method.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thank your for your effort. This way would I still be able to use onBlur logic in child component?

Comment: Your solution calls parent method `onBlur`. My `onBlur` method is defined in child component. It validates input value and outputs `this.error` :) So, I would need to call `onBlur` from parent somehow.